# Error log for server

Tags: linux, tomcat, struts2

hi i developed an struts2 web application on my local machine and its working fine using http://localhost:6060 . but after that i created war file and give that to my admin for deploying [he is using tomcat 5, linux platform], when he tries to deploy war file it is showing false in the tomcat task manager even if you click  start it wont start and display message in the message box.
 **FAIL - Application at context path /Sign_Up could not be started** 
all other deploy war file[struts1.3, .net etc] working fine but mine alone is not working.
here is web.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

in my project folder i am not having server.xml file and when i deploy in application server i am having this error message in log file

```
 Mar 29, 2012 2:58:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
 Mar 29, 2012 2:59:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
 INFO: Deploying web application archive Sign_Up.war
 Mar 29, 2012 2:59:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
 SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
 javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xa                                                      lan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<clinit>(DomHelper.                                             java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loa                                             dConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:830)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loa                                             dDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:131)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.ini                                             t(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(Defau                                             ltConfiguration.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(                                             ConfigurationManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Di                                             spatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.                                             java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(Applicatio                                             nFilterConfig.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(Applica                                             tionFilterConfig.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFi                                             lterConfig.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.                                             java:3635)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4                                             218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase                                             .java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:74                                             0)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:825)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:515                                             )
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1220)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                             java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                             sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:                                             503)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultM                                             BeanServerInterceptor.java:857)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:795                                             )
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:                                             1397)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServ                                             let.java:213)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl                                             icationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF                                             ilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV                                             alve.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV                                             alve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica                                             torBase.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j                                             ava:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j                                             ava:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal                                             ve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav                                             a:151)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java                                             :870)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.p                                             rocessConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpo                                             int.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFol                                             lowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadP                                             ool.java:685)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
   Mar 29, 2012 2:59:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
   SEVERE: Error filterStart
  Mar 29, 2012 2:59:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
  SEVERE: Context [/Sign_Up] startup failed due to previous errors
  Mar 29, 2012 2:59:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
  INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

and here is my context.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Sign_Up"/>
```

please tell me do i need to add any extra configuration files..

Thanks in advance

here is my server.xml file

```
      <!-- Example Server Configuration File -->
  <!-- Note that component elements are nested corresponding to their
 parent-child relationships with each other -->

 <!-- A "Server" is a singleton element that represents the entire JVM,
 which may contain one or more "Service" instances.  The Server
 listens for a shutdown command on the indicated port.

 Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
 define subcomponents such as "Valves" or "Loggers" at this level.
  -->

  <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

    <!-- Comment these entries out to disable JMX MBeans support used for the 
   administration web application -->
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreConfigLifecycleListener"/>

 <!-- Global JNDI resources -->
 <GlobalNamingResources>

 <!-- Test entry for demonstration purposes -->
 <Environment name="simpleValue" type="java.lang.Integer" value="30"/>

 <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users -->
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
   description="User database that can be updated and saved"
       factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
      pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

    </GlobalNamingResources>

   <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
   a single "Container" (and therefore the web applications visible
   within that Container).  Normally, that Container is an "Engine",
   but this is not required.

   Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
   define subcomponents such as "Valves" or "Loggers" at this level.
    -->

   <!-- Define the Tomcat Stand-Alone Service -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

   <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned.  Each Connector passes requests on to the
     associated "Container" (normally an Engine) for processing.

     By default, a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector is established on port 8080.
     You can also enable an SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 by
     following the instructions below and uncommenting the second Connector
     entry.  SSL support requires the following steps (see the SSL Config
     HOWTO in the Tomcat 5 documentation bundle for more detailed
     instructions):
     * If your JDK version 1.3 or prior, download and install JSSE 1.0.2 or
       later, and put the JAR files into "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext".
     * Execute:
         %JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA (Windows)
         $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA  (Unix)
       with a password value of "changeit" for both the certificate and
       the keystore itself.

     By default, DNS lookups are enabled when a web application calls
     request.getRemoteHost().  This can have an adverse impact on
     performance, so you can disable it by setting the
     "enableLookups" attribute to "false".  When DNS lookups are disabled,
     request.getRemoteHost() will return the String version of the
     IP address of the remote client.
   -->

   <!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
   <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
   <!-- Note : To disable connection timeouts, set connectionTimeout value
    to 0 -->

<!-- Note : To use gzip compression you could set the following properties :

           compression="on" 
           compressionMinSize="2048" 
           noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml"
-->

    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
   <!--
   <Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
  -->

   <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
   <Connector port="8009" 
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" />

   <!-- Define a Proxied HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8082 -->
   <!-- See proxy documentation for more information about using this. -->
   <!--
   <Connector port="8082" 
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000"
           proxyPort="80" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
-->

<!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
     every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
     analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
     on to the appropriate Host (virtual host). -->

<!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
<Engine name="Standalone" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
--> 

<!-- Define the top level container in our container hierarchy -->
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

  <!-- The request dumper valve dumps useful debugging information about
       the request headers and cookies that were received, and the response
       headers and cookies that were sent, for all requests received by
       this instance of Tomcat.  If you care only about requests to a
       particular virtual host, or a particular application, nest this
       element inside the corresponding <Host> or <Context> entry instead.

       For a similar mechanism that is portable to all Servlet 2.4
       containers, check out the "RequestDumperFilter" Filter in the
       example application (the source for this filter may be found in
       "$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/filters").

       Note that this Valve uses the platform's default character encoding.
       This may cause problems for developers in another encoding, e.g.
       UTF-8.  Use the RequestDumperFilter instead.

       Also note that enabling this Valve will write a ton of stuff to your
       logs.  They are likely to grow quite large.  This extensive log writing
       will definitely slow down your server.

       Request dumping is disabled by default.  Uncomment the following
       element to enable it. -->
  <!--
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>
  -->

  <!-- Because this Realm is here, an instance will be shared globally -->

  <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
       resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
       that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
       available for use by the Realm.  -->
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
         resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

  <!-- Comment out the old realm but leave here for now in case we
       need to go back quickly -->
  <!--
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
  -->

  <!-- Replace the above Realm with one of the following to get a Realm
       stored in a database and accessed via JDBC -->

  <!--
  <Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
         driverName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
      connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/authority"
     connectionName="test" connectionPassword="test"
          userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"
      userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name" />
  -->

  <!--
  <Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
         driverName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
      connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ntserver:1521:ORCL"
     connectionName="scott" connectionPassword="tiger"
          userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"
      userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name" />
  -->

  <!--
  <Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
         driverName="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"
      connectionURL="jdbc:odbc:CATALINA"
          userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"
      userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name" />
  -->

  <!-- Define the default virtual host
       Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
   -->
  <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
   unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
   xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

    <!-- Defines a cluster for this node,
         By defining this element, means that every manager will be changed.
         So when running a cluster, only make sure that you have webapps in there
         that need to be clustered and remove the other ones.
         A cluster has the following parameters:

         className = the fully qualified name of the cluster class

         clusterName = a descriptive name for your cluster, can be anything

         mcastAddr = the multicast address, has to be the same for all the nodes

         mcastPort = the multicast port, has to be the same for all the nodes

         mcastBindAddress = bind the multicast socket to a specific address

         mcastTTL = the multicast TTL if you want to limit your broadcast

         mcastSoTimeout = the multicast readtimeout 

         mcastFrequency = the number of milliseconds in between sending a "I'm alive" heartbeat

         mcastDropTime = the number a milliseconds before a node is considered "dead" if no heartbeat is received

         tcpThreadCount = the number of threads to handle incoming replication requests, optimal would be the same amount of threads as nodes 

         tcpListenAddress = the listen address (bind address) for TCP cluster request on this host, 
                            in case of multiple ethernet cards.
                            auto means that address becomes
                            InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()

         tcpListenPort = the tcp listen port

         tcpSelectorTimeout = the timeout (ms) for the Selector.select() method in case the OS
                              has a wakup bug in java.nio. Set to 0 for no timeout

         printToScreen = true means that managers will also print to std.out

         expireSessionsOnShutdown = true means that 

         useDirtyFlag = true means that we only replicate a session after setAttribute,removeAttribute has been called.
                        false means to replicate the session after each request.
                        false means that replication would work for the following piece of code: (only for SimpleTcpReplicationManager)
                        <%
                        HashMap map = (HashMap)session.getAttribute("map");
                        map.put("key","value");
                        %>
         replicationMode = can be either 'pooled', 'synchronous' or 'asynchronous'.
                           * Pooled means that the replication happens using several sockets in a synchronous way. Ie, the data gets replicated, then the request return. This is the same as the 'synchronous' setting except it uses a pool of sockets, hence it is multithreaded. This is the fastest and safest configuration. To use this, also increase the nr of tcp threads that you have dealing with replication.
                           * Synchronous means that the thread that executes the request, is also the
                           thread the replicates the data to the other nodes, and will not return until all
                           nodes have received the information.
                           * Asynchronous means that there is a specific 'sender' thread for each cluster node,
                           so the request thread will queue the replication request into a "smart" queue,
                           and then return to the client.
                           The "smart" queue is a queue where when a session is added to the queue, and the same session
                           already exists in the queue from a previous request, that session will be replaced
                           in the queue instead of replicating two requests. This almost never happens, unless there is a 
                           large network delay.
    -->             
    <!--
        When configuring for clustering, you also add in a valve to catch all the requests
        coming in, at the end of the request, the session may or may not be replicated.
        A session is replicated if and only if all the conditions are met:
        1. useDirtyFlag is true or setAttribute or removeAttribute has been called AND
        2. a session exists (has been created)
        3. the request is not trapped by the "filter" attribute

        The filter attribute is to filter out requests that could not modify the session,
        hence we don't replicate the session after the end of this request.
        The filter is negative, ie, anything you put in the filter, you mean to filter out,
        ie, no replication will be done on requests that match one of the filters.
        The filter attribute is delimited by ;, so you can't escape out ; even if you wanted to.

        filter=".*\.gif;.*\.js;" means that we will not replicate the session after requests with the URI
        ending with .gif and .js are intercepted.

        The deployer element can be used to deploy apps cluster wide.
        Currently the deployment only deploys/undeploys to working members in the cluster
        so no WARs are copied upons startup of a broken node.
        The deployer watches a directory (watchDir) for WAR files when watchEnabled="true"
        When a new war file is added the war gets deployed to the local instance,
        and then deployed to the other instances in the cluster.
        When a war file is deleted from the watchDir the war is undeployed locally 
        and cluster wide
    -->

    <!--
    <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
             managerClassName="org.apache.catalina.cluster.session.DeltaManager"
             expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
             useDirtyFlag="true"
             notifyListenersOnReplication="true">

        <Membership 
            className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.mcast.McastService"
            mcastAddr="228.0.0.4"
            mcastPort="45564"
            mcastFrequency="500"
            mcastDropTime="3000"/>

        <Receiver 
            className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.tcp.ReplicationListener"
            tcpListenAddress="auto"
            tcpListenPort="4001"
            tcpSelectorTimeout="100"
            tcpThreadCount="6"/>

        <Sender
            className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.tcp.ReplicationTransmitter"
            replicationMode="pooled"
            ackTimeout="15000"
            waitForAck="true"/>

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.tcp.ReplicationValve"
               filter=".*\.gif;.*\.js;.*\.jpg;.*\.png;.*\.htm;.*\.html;.*\.css;.*\.txt;"/>

        <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                  tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
                  deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
                  watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
                  watchEnabled="false"/>

        <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
    </Cluster>
    -->        



    <!-- Normally, users must authenticate themselves to each web app
         individually.  Uncomment the following entry if you would like
         a user to be authenticated the first time they encounter a
         resource protected by a security constraint, and then have that
         user identity maintained across *all* web applications contained
         in this virtual host. -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all requests for this virtual host.  By
         default, log files are created in the "logs" directory relative to
         $CATALINA_HOME.  If you wish, you can specify a different
         directory with the "directory" attribute.  Specify either a relative
         (to $CATALINA_HOME) or absolute path to the desired directory.
    -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
             directory="logs"  prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
             pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all requests for this virtual host.  By
         default, log files are created in the "logs" directory relative to
         $CATALINA_HOME.  If you wish, you can specify a different
         directory with the "directory" attribute.  Specify either a relative
         (to $CATALINA_HOME) or absolute path to the desired directory.
         This access log implementation is optimized for maximum performance,
         but is hardcoded to support only the "common" and "combined" patterns.
    -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve"
             directory="logs"  prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
             pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
    -->

  </Host>

</Engine>

</Service>

</Server>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your admin machine seems to be missing the [xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/)library

Comment: exactly! all signs to the lib not being in the tomcats lib directory or in some web-inf/conf dir where it can be read.

Comment: so do i need to add that lib to my project web-inf/lib directory or should uploaded to tomcat lib directory if in tomcat tell me exact location where to add @MikeMcMahon

Comment: It's easiest to just dump it in the tomcats lib dir.  That directory depends on the version of tomcat.  You are best to refer to the tomcat docs for your exact version (they changed the directory between versions >5 and <5).  Though previously it was in the tomcats/lib dir.  But yes, you need to include it as the classnotfound def. means it can't find and load the jar containing those classes.

Comment: Thanks Dude Got It after adding Xalan lib it working thanks a lot man @BGR